# Equivalent of constexpr from C++?

Tags: rust

See this code:

```
fn main() {
    let something_const = 42;
    fn multiply(nbr: i32) -> i32 {
        nbr * something_const
    }
    println!("{}", multiply(1));
}
```

`rustc` outputs that

```
error[E0434]: can't capture dynamic environment in a fn item; use the || { ... } closure form instead
  --> main.rs:19:15
   |
19 |         nbr * something_const
   |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

But `something_const` is not dynamic, because it is known at compile time.

Is it an equivalent in Rust of the C++ `constexpr` mechanism?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`constexpr` in C++ can be used in 2 different situations:

- to qualify a constant, and denote that this constant must be available at compile-time
- to qualify a function, and denote that this function must be available for compile-time evaluation

Rust supports both, albeit in a limited fashion:

- you can use `const` to declare a constant, instead of `let`, to declare that it is truly constant
- you can use `const` to qualify a function, to declare that it can be evaluated at compile-time. [Not all functions can be made `const` yet](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/57563).

In your situation, you want the first usage:

```
fn main() {
    const something_const: i32 = 42;

    fn multiply(nbr: i32) -> i32 {
        nbr * something_const
    }

    println!("{}", multiply(1));
}
```

Note that unlike with `let`, it is mandatory to annotate the constant with its type.

Also, the compiler will complain about the naming; constants use `ALL_CAPS`.

Comment: Too bad that the const functions are so limited even on nightly. Basically only tail recursion.

Comment: @AleksanderFular: There is work ongoing on a very capable constant evaluator called [miri](https://github.com/solson/miri) (aka, MIR interpreter). For now, the Rust community is mostly content to "wait it out" and watch solson and oli-obk experiment and see what's possible, what's not, what's too costly, what are the pitfalls, etc... note that MIRI is significantly more advanced than C++'s constexpr: it handles memory allocations!

Comment: @AleksanderFular: Since I was passing by... the [MIRI](https://github.com/solson/miri) project, an interpreter for MIR the Mid-level Intermediate Representation used by rustc, has landed in rustc, and already 1.24 has stabilized a handful of functions as `const` such as `mem::size_of`.

Comment: That's very unfortunate that Rust complains when a constant isn't in all caps. The tradition of marking constants with all caps came from macros, not constants, being all caps to avoid a macro from brutalizing your source code during its search and replace. Take a look at [this article](https://members.accu.org/index.php/articles/1923) for more information about this misunderstanding alongside a strong recommendation to stop yelling in your code when you don't have macros mutating it.

Comment: @user904963: Agreed, I don't like screaming caps either :(

Comment: C++ also supports `if constexpr`. It seems Rust doesn't have any alternatives here.

Comment: @Nawaz: Indeed, `if constexpr` is not directly supported in Rust. Since the question wasn't asking about that, I don't feel it necessary to mention it. C++ also has `consteval`, and `std::is_constant_evaluated`, and others that are related to constants/compile-time evaluations, but the question never asked for a comprehensive answer, just how to solve a particular situation.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: Yes. I understand that. Rust's const computations are very very limited. I cannot do even `N+1` at compile-time. Feeling bad! haha

Comment: @Nawaz: You can (on nightly), you just have to prove there's no overflow. It's a fallout of the decision to avoid -- as much as possible -- monomorphization errors. Most of the time simple arithmetic is enough; it's only problematic for recursion, as then the number of "proofs" is unbounded.

Comment: Yes. But I cannot use nightly in production. It's practically not useful.

Comment: @Nawaz: Nightly works perfectly fine in production ;)

Comment: Haha. Yes usually. I meant.. they are more likely to change..and more likely to have bugs. I'm working on Solana programs. So it needs to be super secure.