# One question about "rustc --explain E0716"

Tags: rust

I read the explanation of [E0716](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#E0716), but still can't thoroughly understand the following code. Why it can be compiled?

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct X {
    a: i32,
    b: i32,
}
let y;
y = &X { a: 1, b: 2 };    // Why didn't it break E0716?
println!("{:?}", y);
```

or

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct X {
    a: i32,
    b: i32,
}
let y;
{
    y = &X { a: 1, b: 2 };
}
println!("{:?}", y);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is a fairly common thing to wonder about; in fact, it's been asked before a couple times, so we already have a ready answer for it. I'm going to mark your question as a duplicate of that one so future askers with the same question will find it too.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a detailed explanation about '<constexpr>'?

Comment: `constexpr` is a C++ keyword for "constant expression" -- i.e. an expression that can be evaluated by the compiler at compile time (because it does not rely on any runtime information). [In Rust we use the `const` keyword for those things](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41346532/3650362). I'm not sure why the RFC uses "constexpr" instead.